# Area calculating code expecting semicolons between method name and default constructor?

Tags: java, notepad++, java.util.scanner

I made code that is supposed to take in user input and calculate either the area of a triangle, circle, or rectangle based on inputted dimensions.  The code gets like 3 errors in the methods that say there should be a semicolon between the method names and the () after the method names.  This is not a "do my homework" post, but I have really sought out all the resources I could find and really just need some help knowing how to do this.  Code is below, and areas that returned the errors are in caps.

```
import java.util.Scanner; 

public class areacalculatorNLW
{ 
private double rektlength;
private double rektwidth;
{
    double GETREKT(){
        System.out.println("Enter the length: ");
        rektlength = scan.next();
        System.out.println("Enter the width: ");
        rektwidth = scan.next();
        double rektarea = rektlength * rektwidth;
        System.out.println(rektarea);
    }
}
private double radius;
{
    double GETCIRCLE(){
        System.out.println("Enter the radius of the circle. ");
        radius = scan.next();
        double circlearea = (radius * Math.PI) * (radius * Math.PI);
        System.out.println(circlearea);
    }
}
private double trianglelength;
private double trianglewidth;
{
    double GETTRIANGLE(){
        System.out.println("Enter the triangle length: ");
        trianglelength = scan.next();
        System.out.println("Enter the triangle width: ");
        trianglewidth = scan.next();
        trianglearea = (trianglelength * trianglewidth) / 2;
        System.out.println(trianglearea);
    }
}


public static void main(String[] args) 
{ 

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Hello, what would you like to calculate?");
    System.out.println("Type 1 to calculate the area of a rectangle.");
    System.out.println("Type 2 to calculate the area of a circle.");
    System.out.println("Type 3 to calculate the area of a triangle.");
    System.out.println("Type 4 to exit the program.");

    int choice;
    choice = scan.nextInt();

    if(choice == 1){
        this.getrekt();
    }

    if (choice == 2){
        this.getcirlce();
    }
    if (choice == 3){
        this.gettriangle();
    }

}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't use `this` in a static method, since it refers to the current instance, which doesn't exist in a static method.

You must create an instance of the class in order to call non static methods :

```
areacalculatorNLW calc = new areacalculatorNLW ();
```

and then call the methods for that instance. For example :

```
calc.GETREKT();
```

Also, you should learn Java naming conventions.

EDIT: As mentioned in other comments/answers, you also have extra curly braces surrounding your methods, which should be removed.

Comment: I don't think that error because of this keyword. that is because of extra parenthesis. or am i wrong ?

Answer (score 2):

There are many problems in your code:

1. Your methods are declared to return a value but has no return statements, change the return value into void.
2. scan.next() returns String. in order to parse it into Double use Double.valueOf method
3. You cant use this in a static scope. in order to use'this' you must have an instance of the object, but static methods are attached to a class and not to an instance, so you can create an instance inside your main method and use it
4. names are case sensitive - you can't name a method FOO and call it foo later.
5. Naming conventions: Classes should start with uppercase letters, methods and variables should be named in camel case and start with lowercase letter (for example myMethod instead of MYMETHOD)
6. when you declare a class it is more acceptable to gather the fields together and the methods together
7. You have also forgot to declare the trianglearea variable

Here is your code after fixing these problems, try to learn fro the changes (and in order to work with this code you must change the file name as well to match the class name:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class AreaCalculator {
    private double trianglearea;
    private double rektlength;
    private double rektwidth;
    private double trianglelength;
    private double trianglewidth;

    void getRect(Scanner scan) {
        System.out.println("Enter the length: ");
        rektlength = Double.valueOf(scan.next());
        System.out.println("Enter the width: ");
        rektwidth = Double.valueOf(scan.next());
        double rektarea = rektlength * rektwidth;
        System.out.println(rektarea);
    }

    private double radius;

    void getCircle(Scanner scan) {
        System.out.println("Enter the radius of the circle. ");
        radius = Double.valueOf(scan.next());
        double circlearea = (radius * Math.PI) * (radius * Math.PI);
        System.out.println(circlearea);
    }

    void getTriangle(Scanner scan) {
        System.out.println("Enter the triangle length: ");
        trianglelength = Double.valueOf(scan.next());
        System.out.println("Enter the triangle width: ");
        trianglewidth = Double.valueOf(scan.next());
        trianglearea = (trianglelength * trianglewidth) / 2;
        System.out.println(trianglearea);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Hello, what would you like to calculate?");
        System.out.println("Type 1 to calculate the area of a rectangle.");
        System.out.println("Type 2 to calculate the area of a circle.");
        System.out.println("Type 3 to calculate the area of a triangle.");
        System.out.println("Type 4 to exit the program.");

        int choice;
        choice = scan.nextInt();

        AreaCalculator AreaCalculator = new AreaCalculator();

        if (choice == 1) {
            AreaCalculator.getRect(scan);
        }

        if (choice == 2) {
            AreaCalculator.getCircle(scan);
        }
        if (choice == 3) {
            AreaCalculator.getTriangle(scan);
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

the shown code has a lot of errors.

Using an IDE such as Eclipse would immediately telling you what is wrong.

A basic syntax error: you surround your methods with (an additional) { } which is an error. A method in Java is like

```
public void foo() {}
```

whereas you wrote

```
{ public void foo() {} }
```

A basic error in understanding: Your main method is a static method. However your other methods are not static. In your main method however there is no instance of your class thus you can not call

```
this.
```

You could fix this by creating an instance with

```
public static void main(String[] args) { 
  Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
  areacalculatorNLW myInstance = new areacalculatorNLW();
  myInstance.getrekt();
  ...
```

Besides that you are using a variable trianglearea which you have nowhere defined and the scan variable from your main method is not visible in the other methods.

I would strongly recommend you to get someone else making some pair programming doing this together with you. You should improve your knowledge of basic Java concepts as otherwise this will take a really long time to get it right.

Answer (score 0):

Remove extra parenthesis :

```
{
    double GETREKT(){
        System.out.println("Enter the length: ");
        rektlength = scan.next();
        System.out.println("Enter the width: ");
        rektwidth = scan.next();
        double rektarea = rektlength * rektwidth;
        System.out.println(rektarea);
    }
}
```

to this

```
    double GETREKT(){
        System.out.println("Enter the length: ");
        rektlength = scan.next();
        System.out.println("Enter the width: ");
        rektwidth = scan.next();
        double rektarea = rektlength * rektwidth;
        System.out.println(rektarea);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class areacalculatorNLW
{ 
private double rektlength;
private double rektwidth;
{  // THE PROBLEM IS HERE.
    double getrekt(){
        System.out.println("Enter the length: ");
        rektlength = scan.next();
```

You have put extra curly braces, marked as above. Whole methods don't need those; only mothod bodies.